# Is function name also a namespace?

Tags: c++, namespaces

I'm new to c++ and was reading up about namespaces on [dfs-minded](https://dfs-minded.com/the-ultimate-c-namespaces-tutorial/) and came across this,

```
using my_fancy_app::HelpfulFunc; // bring it to the scope
HelpfulFunc();
 
// or just
 
my_fancy_app::HelpfulFunc(); // fully qualified name
```

My doubt is why HelpfulFunc is appended to 'using myfancy_app'. Can't we just do:

```
using my_fancy_app;
HelpfulFunc();
```

Comment: Well, in the latter code snippet, you'd have to write `using namespace my_fancy_app;`. And that would mean that everything defined in the `my_fancy_app::` namespace would get brought in. This pulls in just `HelpfulFunc` without pulling everything else in the `my_fancy_app` namespace. If you only want that one function from `my_fancy_app` and don't want to worry about name collisions from using the entire namespace, it's what you'd do.

Comment: @NathanPierson Ah i see. Can you clarify why we didn't have to use 'namespace' keyword in the first code snippet?

Comment: @Jamāl Because `my_fancy_app::HelpfulFunc` isn't a namespace (which I hope answers your question)

Comment: @Kevin ok got it, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is function name also a namespace?

No. Function name is not a namespace.

> ```
> my_fancy_app::HelpfulFunc(); // fully qualified name
> ```

The comment is a bit wrong. That is a qualified name, but not a dully qualified name. A fully qualified name would be `::my_fancy_app::HelpfulFunc`.

Comment: The call `my_fancy_app::HelpfulFunc()` is different to `::my_fancy_app::HelpfulFunc()` only if it is called inside another namespace right?

Comment: @Jamāl Yes. Even then, it can resolve to another function only if `::my_fancy_app` has been hidden by another name.

Comment: Hmm. I don't see how a global namespace can be hidden by another namespace. Can you please explain?

Comment: @Jamāl `::my_fancy_app` is not the global namespace. `::` is the global namespace.

Comment: Shouldn't it properly be called `::other_namespace::my_fancy_app` then?

Comment: @Jamāl That could be a fully qualified name of something that hides `::my_fancy_app` within `::other_namespace`.

Comment: Hmm, I have to ponder over this for a bit. Anyway it steers off a bit from my main question about function namespace which you have answered. I will accept the answer. Thanks a lot for giving me a direction to keep thinking.